# Removing dead content provider: contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am trying to fetch all contacts with all details(email list, phone number list, image, name etc) from my device phone book. I have 600 contacts on my device.

I am trying to fetch contacts through an asynchronous task, but before fetching all the data, the application closes without any warning or any error.

I am getting a "Removing dead content provider: contacts" message in my logcat.

How to solve this kind of issue.

Comment: Hey , buddy , did you get any solution for this , i am getting same error after updating some portions of my application .

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got the solution for your problem , i was facing the same .Suddenly i found that i was not checking the method that is used to get the bitmap photo attach with all contacts .I forget to close the cursor in that method and hence it occupied memory objects of heap allocated to app .Your activity thread gets killed when this heap does not have any extra memory to allocate to your application .
Yor couldnt find anything in the logcat because you was looking for the error on specific to your application while you can see error of memObj and Process Runtime Exception on phone level logs (All messages option of logcat)